# Rails AWS SQS queue is polling messages indefinitely, due to this server is flooded with repetitive logs of size in GBs

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-sqs

```
        poller.poll(skip_delete: true) do |raw_payload|
          msg_obj = Wrs::Events::Message.from_platform_payload raw_payload.body
          Rails.logger.info "Wrs::Events -> poller_triggered: #{msg_obj.action}"
          Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_class
            .send(Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_method, msg_obj)
          poller.delete_message(raw_payload)
        end
        rescue StandardError => e
            Rails.logger.error "Error encountered while polling:\n#{e.message.inspect}"
            raise
        end
```

this is the event handling block in my application, now i am not able to find the reason of repetitive logs issue while using SQS.

Logs are generated in the event handling logic of this method

```
 Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_class
            .send(Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_method, msg_obj)
```

Previously there was no explicit deletion of the message but i have implement the above method so that it can remove the message from after successful processing.
but it have not improved.

```
      poller.poll do |raw_payload|
          msg_obj = Wrs::Events::Message.from_platform_payload raw_payload.body
          Rails.logger.info "Wrs::Events -> poller_triggered: #{msg_obj.action}"
          Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_class
            .send(Wrs::Events::Subscriber.event_handler_method, msg_obj)
      end
```

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand the question. The [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v2/api/Aws/SQS/QueuePoller.html) are fairly clear *"By default, polling will continue indefinitely..."*. There are some ways to control what you are doing such as using `max_number_of_messages` to retrieve multiple messages at once, using `idle_timeout` to stop polling after a period of time where no messages are received but I am currently not 100% certain what your intent is